# could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 23

Tags: java, spring

I want to send 2 dates to Spring rest point. I tried this:

```
start_date=2019-03-03T21:25:24.000Z&end_date=2019-03-03T21:25:29.000Z
```

Rest End point:

```
    @GetMapping("/terminals")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<Integer, List<TopTerminalsDTO>>> getTopTerminals(
            @RequestParam(value = "start_date", required = true) String start_date,
            @RequestParam(value = "end_date", required = true) String end_date) {

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        LocalDateTime start_dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(start_date, formatter);
        LocalDateTime end_dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(end_date, formatter);

        final List<PaymentTransactionsDailyFacts> list = dashboardService.findTop_Terminals(start_dateTime, end_dateTime);
```

But I get exception:

```
2019-03-10 13:22:46,677 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 13:22:46.676 [default task-1] ERROR o.s.b.w.s.support.ErrorPageFilter - Forwarding to error page from request [/dashboard/terminals] due to exception [Text '2019-03-03T21:22:39.000Z' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 23]
2019-03-10 13:22:46,678 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-03-03T21:22:39.000Z' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 23
2019-03-10 13:22:46,678 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2049)
2019-03-10 13:22:46,678 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1948)
2019-03-10 13:22:46,679 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
2019-03-10 13:22:46,679 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at deployment.datalis_admin.war//org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.DashboardController.getTopTerminals(DashboardController.java:87)
2019-03-10 13:22:46,679 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Do you know how I can fix this?

EDIT:

```
LocalDateTime start_dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(start_date, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT);
        LocalDateTime end_dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(end_date, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT);
```

I get: `23:15:21,554 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3) java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-03-19T23:15:14.000Z' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {NanoOfSecond=0, InstantSeconds=1553037314, MicroOfSecond=0, MilliOfSecond=0},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is because according to your `DateTimeFormatter` start_date is invalid. It is not exepcting to have `Z` at the very end of the date.

You have 2 options.

1. Remove `Z` character from your `start_date` & `end_date`.
2. Modify `DateTimeFormatter` to accept ZoneOffset as well.

Example:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
```

You can also decide if fraction of a second in your `start_date` is not necessary. If not you can use this trick:

```
LocalDateTime start_dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2019-03-03T21:25:24Z", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT);
```

Comment: I get  `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-03-19T23:15:14.000Z' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {NanoOfSecond=0, InstantSeconds=1553037314, MicroOfSecond=0, MilliOfSecond=0},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed`

Comment: And which code snippet are you using? What kind of option did you pick?

Comment: The second one.

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste your newest code below with **EDIT** header?

Comment: I wrote that **if fraction of a second in your start_date is not necessary.** It means that you have no milliseconds in your parameter. You still have it so it will not work for you unless you will switch to `2019-03-19T23:15:14Z` instead of `2019-03-19T23:15:14.000Z`. Please use `DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");` for your case

Comment: Just realized that i missed *not* word somehow. Edited my answer.

Comment: I use Java 11. Is there a better way to parse the date?

Comment: I am not sure if Java11 (or even 9) introduced anything which could make it better. I mean that your solution and my answer are simple to implement and easy to read.